# How to handle animation that contains multiple objects in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, render

I need to create an OpenGL animation, which mainly contains two objects, a simple one (e.g. a plane) that consists of hundreds of vertexes, and a very complex one (e.g. a city) that contains hundreds of thousands of vertexes. Both two objects have been created indecently. Now I need to put both of them into an animation. For example, in the animation we are looking down at the city from the sky, while a plane flying through the screen. Since the city model is very complex and takes minutes to render, it is impossible to render both the plane and the city at every frame. So my question is, how to render multiple objects independently in OpenGL? Do I need to render the city at every frame? Can I kind of "fix" the city object and just refresh the plane at every frame?

I've read references such as the Red Book etc. Maybe I don't get it but they seem not teach how to handle the above problem. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

> Since the city model is very complex and takes minutes to render,

Minutes for less than 1 million vertices? Modern GPUs can push out hundreds of millions of vertices per second! You should get rid of that bottleneck, not try to plaster over it with layered rendering.

Have a look at your code. Are ther calls to `glBegin` and `glVertex`? If so, then that's where your problem is. Those calls are slooow. Don't use them. Use vertex arrays and vertex buffer objects to batch things up nicely for the GPU.

> So my question is, how to render multiple objects independently in OpenGL?

Technically *every* triangle renders independently from all the other triangles. You probably think about layered rendering. Don't do this, unless you know what you're doing (you're not BTW).

Comment: Thanks datenwolf!

Yes I used glBegin and glVertex. I'm not familiar with vertex arrays and vertex buffer objects, or layered rendering. Could you recommend some references?

Comment: @Aaron: Layered rendering is probably a too advanced topic for you to tackle right now; you must know all aspects of reasterizers like OpenGL implementations are to make effective use of it. Vertex Arrays are the recommended way of drawing things with OpenGL since 1996; any tutorial that still uses glBegin / glVertex is not worth reading. This is IMHO the best tutorial on OpenGL there currently is: http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/

Comment: Thanks! I mainly followed the samples on the Red Book 7th edition in this practice. I will look into VAO and VBO as you recommended. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: For "minutes to render", I guessed the asker might be re-reading a .obj file every frame, then re-reading it again to look up each vertex by its index.